# phpDocumentor with PHP 7.1 Return Type Declarations

Tags: symfony, php-7, phpdoc, php-7.1, phpdocumentor2

We are attempting to start using phpDocumentor for a Symfony 3 site running PHP 7.1.

We are using return type declarations on nearly every entity to keep things clean. phpDocumentor does not seem to support this although I see several references to PHP 7 support on their GitHub.

This is the error for every single entity:
Parse Error: Syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{'

Comment: I'm using phpDocumentor just fine with 7.1 return types. Composer shows that I'm at version 2.9.0.

Comment: I was running version 2.8.5 which apparently doesn't support PHP 7.0. Now it looks like it doesn't support optionals which was a new feature in 7.1: Syntax error, unexpected '?'

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "optionals", I don't see any similarly named feature in the 7.1 list.

Comment: Sorry, nullable types. It is the first feature on here: http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php

Comment: Ah ok, yes, I'm seeing this as well. I think they're just up to 7.0 and not 7.1 You might [file a bug](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues) on their GitHub. I noted earlier this week that it doesn't recognize the new `iterable` type either.

Comment: Thanks, I posted the issue on their Github. https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues/1833

Answer (score -1):

I encountered this problem when I migrated from `PHP 5` to `PHP 7.1` on `Ubuntu / Linux`, so you need to make sure that you are really using `PHP 7.x`!

- Click on any route name on your`Symfony`profiler, then click to `Configuration`(left bottom) and check your `PHP Configuration`. In my
  case `7.1.9-1+ubuntu17.04.1+deb.sury.org+1`. Or simply display     `phpinfo()`;
- If you still using PHP < 7.x that means you need to enable `PHP 7.x` and disable other versions :

  `sudo a2enmod php7.1`

  `sudo a2dismod phpx.x`

  `sudo service apache2 restart`

**Nb:** I assume that you are using `Ubuntu / Linux`.